# Should I register an SEH handler and catch CPU exceptions in my library?

Tags: c++, windows, exception, seh

I am having a custom exception class for my library. I would like to know whether I should register an SEH handler and catch CPU exceptions such as access violation, illegal instruction, divide by zero. I then can report these to the client of my library that a CPU exception has occurred.

Comment: I think this is more a Windows question that a C++ one.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are writing a specific system-related library that really require that, you shouldn't register SEH handlers. If you do that, you are hiding errors to the application.

First rule should be not handling SEH exceptions and allow the application to do it as they were configured.

But if you expect that the program could be crash because an exception when invoking your library (for instance, because it calls to an external API that you know that could raise an exception), you must evaluate if it worth to catch them to take any action (like report an error). But in that case, limit the scope of the exception protection and the filter the narrower as possible.

If the system exceptions are caused by your own code, it shouldn't be hidden and them should be fixed soon.